# My android studio new Thread(new Runnable ) didn't work

Tags: java, android, multithreading, get

I want to use GET() connection in android studio.
And here is my code in MainActivity.java.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        data=findViewById(R.id.bright);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            requestPermissions(new String[]{"android.permission.INTERNET"},1);
            Gushen();
        }
    }
    public void Gushen(){
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                    Log.w("sss","gushen");
                    Request request = new Request.Builder().url("http://iot-api.heclouds.com/thingmodel/query-thing-model?product_id=w50WLDzGBb").build();
                    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                    String responseData = response.body().string();
                    Log.w("sss",responseData);
                    parseJSONWithGSON(responseData);


                    JsonRootBean app = new Gson().fromJson(responseData, JsonRootBean.class);
                    List<Datastreams> streams = app.getData().getDatastreams();
                    List<Datapoints> points = streams.get(0).getDatapoints();
                    value = points.get(0).getValue();
                    data.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            data.setText(String.format("Light is:%s", value));
                        }
                    });
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();}
            }
        });
    }
```

I cannot get "                    Log.w("sss","gushen");
"in my logcat because it is in the new Thread. And I also seem not to get connected to this URL.
here is the screenshot of my logcat.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiTtS.png)

How can I successfully use my new thread and see the result of Log.w of it in the logcat?
And I didn't know if I get connected to the URL by using GET().

Comment: Log messages are not restricted to certain threads, if you don't get log messages then the code is not executed.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to start the thread: in the second-to-last line of the method, replace `});` with `}).start();`